# How do I avoid the warning about my station being too spread out and build a bigger station?

Tags: openttd

Adjacent to one of my cities is one of the larger airports. Adjacent to *that* I'd like to place as large a train station as possible. However when I attempt to place a 7x7 station I get an error message telling me the station is too spread out. How do I avoid such an error?

(I also have bus and truck depots on the periphery of the airport as well.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to break the station in to separate stations and use a load of feeder links, you will need to tweak the advanced option that limits your maximum station spread.

This [advanced setting](http://wiki.openttd.org/Advanced_Settings/Stations#Max_station_spread) (specifically `Stations`→`Max station spread`) can be adjusted to values between 4 and 64, with a default of 12, and determines the maximum size square that can be allowed to bound each station (whether compound or not).

The recommendation is to *only* increase this if you are using the YAPF pathfinder, but this is the default so if you've never tweaked that setting there's no need to worry.

For more information, you can see the wiki entries for the [setting](http://wiki.openttd.org/Advanced_Settings/Stations#Max_station_spread) and [station spread](http://wiki.openttd.org/Change_station_spread).

If you need a station larger than 64 by 64, well then I think you're stuck (and possibly doing it wrong).